# ZipArchive correct Import statement query

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip

I looked at many tutorials, but want to run the ZipArchive (maybe System.IO.Compress ??) so I can do compression by code only.

I also tried adding Stream but this does not resolve the issue below and I've tried a few ways. I need to add multiple files long term.

Errors:

1. ZipArchiveMode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
2. Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:

   > 'Public Sub New(path As String)': Argument matching parameter 'path' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.
   >   'Public Sub New(stream As System.IO.Stream)': Argument matching parameter 'stream' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.IO.Stream'.  t

Code:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnRunZip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunZip.Click

        Using memoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Using archive = New ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, True)

                Dim demoFile = archive.CreateEntry("\compressthese\testfile.txt")

                Using entryStream = demoFile.Open()
                    Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(entryStream)
                        streamWriter.Write(entryStream)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            Using fileStream = New FileStream("C:\folder\test.zip", FileMode.Create)
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: VB will fix the `ZipArchiveMode` one - use the mouse to open the suggestion list...it will import or qualify the reference for you.  Which `New` in there is causing the other problem?

Comment: I've added Imports System.IO.Compression to check if that helps. With or without that when I check ZipArchiveMode is wants to change it to ZipArchive, when I do this the .Create" part no long functions and it still does not understand ZipArchive. I am running .Net 4.5 do I need to import anything else maybe. The code is shown in full.